# IEnumerable List Manipulation

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable

I am using LINQ to generate two separate lists of items. However, I need to merge these two lists in a specific way. I already am sorting by a specific attribute (sequence number) and doing some other magic to ensure that everything is where it should be, but the resulting set is eluding me.

Here is what I have so far:

```
List<item> list1 = { item1, item2, item3, item7, item8, item11, item12 }
List<item> list2 = { item4, item5, item6, 
                     item4, item5, item6, 
                     item9, item10, 
                     item9, item10 }
```

The resulting set should look like this:

```
List<item> listFinal = { item1, item2, item3, 
                         item4, item5, item6, 
                         item4, item5, item6, 
                         item7, item8, 
                         item9, item10, 
                         item9, item10, 
                         item11, item12 }
```

Essentially, I need the final list to include the repeated items in order regardless of how many sets of repeated items there are. There could be one, many or none.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this using LINQ on the two sets I have? Or would I have to use if statements to concatenate the lists?

Comment: What "order" would you like them in?  Does the `item` have a property which suggests this order?

Comment: The order should be as shown in the list final above. I spaced out the lines like that for readability.

Comment: @EricOlson do you want to sort your items by their name ? or some kind of property/field ? can you give us more detail about item class ?

Comment: Your code above shows the order by variable name.  You need to provide a value.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the value is. It could be anything. I have the values I need and am sorting by them. Each of the items has a sequence number and that's what I am using. The above code is highly simplified.

Comment: @Selman22 ... absolutely. Each item is a type with a property called Sequence. The numbers above represent the sequence number used. So, the sorting would be on the sequence number of each item. I tried to make the code as simple as possible above. My apologies for not explaining properly.

Comment: @EricOlson I understand.Your items are ordered and you want to keep that order and concatenate the items but still I need more info about how is your class and lists look like (not simplified version, show the original code if it's possible)

Comment: @Selman22 ... That's a bit easier said than done. I have two rather large LINQ statements generating the above result sets by combining two different XML files. The item class shown above has 25 properties and the only one I use for sorting is an integer field called Sequence. I am not sure how to post long bits of code here in the comments section, so let's assume that the above lists are the sets I get. Each one of those items has a Sequence and I need to get the final list sequenced as shown. Concat will not work as it just adds the items to the list in order, not the order I need.

Comment: I don't think there's anything built-in that will help you out in this case. Is there a second property that you use the sort the initial lists, or could you perhaps use nested lists? That might be a more helpful direction. Otherwise, I can't think of a way to do this without getting fussy, stepping through the list to find the first item that is larger than the current one, and even that wouldn't really work if you have multiple sets in the second list as you do in the first.

Comment: For example, if you had a structure like `{ { item4, item5, item6 }, { item4, item5, item6 }, { item9, item10 }, { item9, item10 } }` instead, you could sort by the first item in each sublist. You could always do a `.SelectMany()` at the end to flatten the lists if you needed to.

Comment: @Hannele - Yeah, that's what I was afraid of. I did not think there was an easy way with LINQ to accomplish this. I was already incredibly surprised with one of the statements I used to create the second list so I was hoping to strike gold again. Thank you for your input!

Comment: @EricOlson check my update and try to implement that method for your class.

Comment: @Hannele - well, I am using a Key Value pair to store the information in the second list BEFORE making the list shown above. It's Key is the sequence number and the Value is a list of `{ item4, item4, item4 }` I wonder if that would be easier to use.

Comment: Selman22's answer below could work, but I still think the better approach would be to look at how you are arriving at these lists, sorted in this specific way, because that is the information you'll *really* need to make sure you're sorting things consistently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var resultList = list1.Concat(list2).OrderBy(x => x.Something).ToList();
```

**UPDATE:** According to your comments, here is an extension method that you can use.Since you don't tell us how your class look like, I just create a class an interface for example.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ConcatItems<T>(this IList<T> source, IList<T> dest)
        where T: ISequence
{
     int index = 0;

     foreach (var x in source)
     {
         if (x.SequenceNumber < dest[index].SequenceNumber)
         {
             dest.Insert(index, x);
             continue;
         }
         while(x.SequenceNumber > dest[index].SequenceNumber) index++;

         if (index != dest.Count - 1 && x.SequenceNumber == dest[index].SequenceNumber)
         {
             while (index != dest.Count -1 && 
                 Math.Abs(dest[index].SequenceNumber - dest[index + 1].SequenceNumber) == 1) index++;

              if (index != dest.Count - 1) dest.Insert(index, x);
              else dest.Add(x);
              continue;
         }
         dest.Insert(index, x);
     }

     return dest;
}
```

Interface and Class:

```
public interface ISequence
{
    int SequenceNumber { get; set; }
}
class Item : ISequence
{
    public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }

    public Item(int number)
    {
        SequenceNumber = number;
    }
}
```

Here is the usage (`list1` and `list2` are `List<Item>`):

```
var result = list1.ConcatItems(list2);
```

The method is working exactly what you want but you should implement it according to your situation and that part is up to you...

Here is a demonstration on `LINQPad`:

List1:

[image]

List2:

[image]

Output:

[image]

**Last note:** This method assumes your items are ordered.If they are not, first sort your items then call the method:

```
Comparison<Item> comp = (x, y) => x.SequenceNumber.CompareTo(y.SequenceNumber);
list1.Sort(comp);
list2.Sort(comp);
var result = list1.ConcatItems(list2);
```

Comment: Don't forget to assign the result.

Comment: Hmm ... ok. Let me see if that will work. I don't think it will as I have to get the repeated sets in order individually. Like this: 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6. This statement looks like it will give me 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6. Not exactly what I need.

Comment: @Selman22 - This looks good. Let me try it and see. Thank you!

Comment: @EricOlson there was a problem at the end now I fixed it.now it appends last 11-12 to the end of the second list.

Comment: @Selman22 - THANKS! This was a HUGE help. I appreciate your work on this. I will get this info into my test and try it out. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AddRange method from a list to combine another list of the same type.  Wouldn't that accomplish what you are trying to do?

Comment: Add Range? Ok ... that might work ... I will have to tweak it a bit to try it out, but that sounds about right.

Comment: Eric, you would basically just do "list1.AddRange(list2);", and that would replace your listFinal.  That should work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
var list = list1.Concat(list2);
```